# Is it possible to run some Wasm code from the browser console?

Tags: webassembly

I'm reading this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Loading_and_running, and they propose to fetch (as in xhr fetch) the `.wasm` file first, and run it.

Let's say I have a small piece of wasm code (like [this one here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API#Preparing_the_example) converted into `.wasm`) as a string. How can I paste it in a variable and run it in my browser console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example, with the following WASM code, that exports a single `wasm_add` function:

```
(module
  (type $t0 (func (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (func $wasm_add (type $t0) (param $p0 i32) (param $p1 i32) (result i32)
    get_local $p1
    get_local $p0
    i32.add)
  (table $T0 0 anyfunc)
  (memory $memory 1)
  (export "memory" (memory 0))
  (export "wasm_add" (func $wasm_add)))
```

You can convert your small wasm code to a list of integers, for instance, using Python:

```
f = open('code.wasm','rb')
code_as_integers = [s for s in f.read()]
f.close()
code
```

Results in a list of integers such as

```
[0, 97, 115, 109, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 135, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 96, 2, 127, 127, 1, 127, 3, 130, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 0, 4, 132, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 112, 0, 0, 5, 131, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 0, 1, 6, 129, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 7, 149, 128, 128, 128, 0, 2, 6, 109, 101, 109, 111, 114, 121, 2, 0, 8, 119, 97, 115, 109, 95, 97, 100, 100, 0, 0, 10, 141, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 135, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 32, 1, 32, 0, 106, 11]
```

Then, in the browser's console type

```
wasmCode = new Uint8Array([0, 97, 115, 109, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 135, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 96, 2, 127, 127, 1, 
      127, 3, 130, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 0, 4, 132, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 112, 0, 0, 5, 131, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 
      0, 1, 6, 129, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 7, 149, 128, 128, 128, 0, 2, 6, 109, 101, 109, 111, 114, 121, 2, 0, 8, 
      119, 97, 115, 109, 95, 97, 100, 100, 0, 0, 10, 141, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 135, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 32, 1, 
      32, 0, 106, 11])
let instance;
WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmCode).then( ( module ) => { instance = module.instance; } )
```

Then, you'll see your exports in the `instance` variable and you can invoke functions in it from the console, such as

```
let sum = instance.exports.wasm_add(1,2);
```